# Fetch all the details of android app from google play

Tags: android

Can anybody please tell me how to fetch all the details of android app including icon, screenshots and description from google play using its package name? If there is any api for this then please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Store API is an unofficial version of Google Play Store which will let you pullup applications from google play store using18 different functions covering almost everything from google store

Tryit: https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API

Comment: @ThanhLe Can you provide me the api address i want to use this api get detail of apps in a android app/